# Pass pointer as a param to template

Tags: c++

I have a sketch of my own array class and array comparison rule

CArray.h

```
template <typename T>
    class CArray
    {
    public:

        CArray();
        virtual void setComparisonRule(IArrayComparisonRule<T>* comparisonRule);

    private:

        IArrayComparisonRule<T>* comparisonRule;    
    };
```

CArray.cpp

```
template <typename T>
    void CArray<T>::setComparisonRule(IArrayComparisonRule<T>* comparisonRule)
    {
        this->comparisonRule = comparisonRule;
    }
```

IArrayComparisonRule

```
template <typename T>
    class IArrayComparisonRule
    {

    public:

        virtual b1 isLeftEqualRight(const T* leftItem, const T* rightItem) = 0;
        virtual b1 isLeftLessThenRight(const T* leftItem, const T* rightItem) = 0;
        virtual b1 isLeftGraterThenRight(const T* leftItem, const T* rightItem) = 0;
        virtual b1 isLeftLessOrEqualThenRight(const T* leftItem, const T* rightItem) = 0;
        virtual b1 isLeftGraterOrEqualThenRight(const T* leftItem, const T* rightItem) = 0;
    };
```

Array element

```
class Sample
{
public:
    si32 value;

    Sample(si32 value = 0)
            : value{value}
    {}

    ~Sample()
    {}
};
```

IArrayComparisonRule implementation

```
class SampleComparisonRule : public IArrayComparisonRule<Sample>
{

public:

    b1 isLeftEqualRight(const Sample* leftItem, const Sample* rightItem)
    {
        return leftItem->value == rightItem->value;
    }

    b1 isLeftLessThenRight(const Sample* leftItem, const Sample* rightItem)
    {
        return leftItem->value < rightItem->value;
    }

    b1 isLeftGraterThenRight(const Sample* leftItem, const Sample* rightItem)
    {
        return leftItem->value > rightItem->value;
    }

    b1 isLeftLessOrEqualThenRight(const Sample* leftItem, const Sample* rightItem)
    {
        return leftItem->value <= rightItem->value;
    }

    b1 isLeftGraterOrEqualThenRight(const Sample* leftItem, const Sample* rightItem)
    {
        return leftItem->value >= rightItem->value;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
CArray<Sample*> objects;
objects.setComparisonRule(new SampleComparisonRule());
```

As you can see I use T as template for both CArray and IArrayComparisonRule.

The compiler (GCC 5.4.0) error is **no matching function for call to ‘ee::CArray::setComparisonRule(SampleComparisonRule*)’**

When I pass Sample as a pointer to template:

```
class SampleComparisonRule : public IArrayComparisonRule<Sample*>

template <typename T*>
    class IArrayComparisonRule
```

the compiler says: **expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T’**

From my point of view, the problem can be solved if I pass Sample as pointer to IArrayComparisonRule. How can I do that? Maybe there is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The error is you have your template syntax wrong. Should be `template<typename T> //...`

Comment: I hope you know about [Why templates can only be implemented in Header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CArray<Sample> objects;`?

Comment: There is no problem with .cpp inclusion. I've just included it in CArray.h and in works good.

Comment: No, I need array of Sample pointers. CArray<Sample*> objects;

Comment: Then you need `class SampleComparisonRule : public IArrayComparisonRule<Sample *>`.

Comment: When I do that I get  "invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘SampleComparisonRule’" compiler error

Comment: That's because it doesn't implement the virtual functions with the right type signature. Should be `b1 isLeftEqualRight(Sample *const *leftItem, Sample *const *rightItem)`, etc.

Comment: It seems to work. How can I access to value of leftItem? The leftItem->value doesn't work

Comment: `(*leftItem)->value`, but passing by reference instead of by pointer would make the code cleaner.

Comment: Thank you guys! I solved my problem with your help!